# What is a practical workflow for knowing when typescript code finished compiling and is ready to run in the browser?

Tags: typescript

What is a practical workflow for knowing when typescript code finished compiling and is ready to run in the browser?

In JavaScript, my workflow was:

1. Edit code in IDE
2. CMD-tab to browser (IDE auto-saves file)
3. CMD+R to refresh

In Java, my workflow was:

1. Edit code in IDE
2. Press "Compile and Run" button in IDE

These workflows have the desirable characteristics that they have a small number of manual steps and no risk of running stale code.

What is a practical workflow for typescript?  I'd like to meet as many of these requirements as possible:

- Never run stale code in the browser
- Minimize manual steps and/or cognitive load
- Zero or low overhead to switch between many HTML page entry points (ideally could be done in the browser)
- Works well on at least Mac and Windows

Here are some possibilities:

Workflow A: Manual compilation

1. Edit code in IDE
2. Press a keystroke in the IDE that compiles the code, and wait for compilation to finish
3. CMD+tab to the browser
4. CMD+R to refresh

This workflow has the disadvantage that I am responsible for starting the compilation and paying attention to see when compilation completes.

Workflow B: Watch mode

1. Edit code in IDE
2. CMD-tab to browser.  IDE auto saves file, and tsc --watch (or the IDE) automatically recompiles files
3. CMD+R to refresh

This workflow has the disadvantage that if I refresh the browser too soon, then I get stale code, and there is no convenient signal to know when compilation is done unless I watch the watch process.

Workflow C: Watch mode + browser open

1. Edit code in IDE
2. CMD tab to browser. IDE saves file and webpack watch mode can automatically open a browser page when compilation finishes.

This sounds inconvenient because (a) webpack will open pages whenever my code is saved and (b) more work to update entry points in a webpack config file when I want to test another entry point.

What do you do in practice, and what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

It has been working well to use `tsc -b --watch` in a separate window. Then after editing code, you can (a) save file or (b) reformat code (which, in my case, triggers a file save) or (c) switch to the browser (which, in my case, triggers a file save).  As long as the `tsc -b --watch` window is visible, it is easy to when the browser can be manually refreshed, or if there is a type error.  Using a tsconfig that watches multiple projects supports multiple entry points well.